# Missing '='. in Debian service

Tags: linux, debian, services, daemon

I've created this service in /etc/systemd/system/webapp.service

in a:

```
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release:    10
```

This is the content:

```
[Unit]
Description=webapp daemon
[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/start-webapp.sh
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/stop-webapp.sh
ExecReload=/usr/local/bin/reload-webapp.sh
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I try to startd the service using:

```
sudo systemctl start webapp.service
```

But when I do

```
sudo systemctl status webapp.service
```

I got this error:

```
● webapp.service - webapp daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/webapp.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)

Jun 01 11:31:48 localhost systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/webapp.service:8: Missing '='.
Jun 01 11:31:52 localhost systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/webapp.service:8: Missing '='.
Jun 01 11:35:21 localhost systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/webapp.service:8: Missing '='.
Jun 01 11:35:31 localhost systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/webapp.service:8: Missing '='.
```

and

```
admin@localhost:/etc/systemd/system$ cat -vetn webapp.service 
     1  [Unit]$
     2  Description=webapp daemon$
     3  [Service]$
     4  Type=simple$
     5  ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/start-webapp.sh$
     6  ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/stop-webapp.sh$
     7  ExecReload=/usr/local/bin/reload-webapp.sh$
     8  [Install]$
     9  WantedBy=multi-user.target$
```

Comment: Look for special characters, e.g. carriage-return at the end of line 7. `cat -vetn` will show these characters and a `$` for the end of the line.

Comment: Is whitespace permitted around the assignments (`Type = simple`)? All the documentation that I've seen uses `Type=simple`

Comment: From man [systemd.syntax](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.syntax.html) *...key=value. Whitespace immediately before or after the "=" is ignored.*

Comment: I've removed with the same result :-(

Comment: Multiply posted at https://stackoverflow.com/q/62129540 .